# How to change spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize in Runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipart

In `application.properties` I have:

```
spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize
spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize
```

But I want to have possibility to change this property without application restart.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Not possible unless you want to use spring cloud config server

Comment: @pvpkiran, What is spring cloud config?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Comment: maybe you can try to get stuff working by using [MultipartConfigFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/MultipartConfigFactory.html) in your code manually

Comment: what MultipartResolver do you use?

Comment: @Nikita Gorbachevski, I use **StandardServletMultipartResolver**

Comment: @Patrick it is not rnough for me. Please, provide details

Comment: @gstackoverflow would you like to update it on per-request basis or time to time for all requests?

Comment: @Nikita Gorbachevski, I want to update it on per-request basis

Comment: @gstackoverflow i've already provided solution for both cases )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging in source code i found a way how to do it for `StandardServletMultipartResolver`.

`StandardServletMultipartResolver` wraps `HttpServletRequest` with `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest` which uses standard servlet api implementation of `request.getParts()` for processing multipart request. Internally this method uses `MultipartConfigElement` which is set by `ServletRegistrationBean` during registration of dispatcher servlet. We are interested in `MultipartConfigElement` cause it contains properties we are interested in.

By default `ServletRegistrationBean` gets `MultipartConfigElement` from `MultipartAutoConfiguration`. Default implementation of `MultipartConfigElement` doesn't allow to modify its properties so we need to extend this class to add such ability. Further implementation depends on whether you want to modify parameters on per request basis or time to time for the whole application.

*Per request basis*

`MultipartConfigurationContext` stores configuration for a particular request. `UpdateMultipartConfigurationFilter` sets multipart properties for given request. `UpdatableMultipartConfigElement` uses this information if provided.

```
public class MultipartConfigurationContext {

    private static ThreadLocal<Integer> maxFileSize = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setMaxFileSize(Integer val) {
        maxFileSize.set(val);
    }

    public static Integer getMaxFileSize() {
        return maxFileSize.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        maxFileSize.set(null);
    }
}

public class UpdatableMultipartConfigElement extends MultipartConfigElement {

    private final long maxFileSize;

    public UpdatableMultipartConfigElement(String location, long maxFileSize, long maxRequestSize, int fileSizeThreshold) {
        super(location, maxFileSize, maxRequestSize, fileSizeThreshold);
        this.maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
    }

    @Override
    public long getMaxFileSize() {
        return MultipartConfigurationContext.getMaxFileSize() == null
                ? maxFileSize : MultipartConfigurationContext.getMaxFileSize();
    }
}

public class UpdateMultipartConfigurationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter implements Ordered {

    // this filter must be before OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter
    public static final int ORDER = FilterRegistrationBean.REQUEST_WRAPPER_FILTER_MAX_ORDER - 20000;

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return ORDER;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // gets file size from request if present and sets it to MultipartConfigurationContext
        MultipartConfigurationContext.setMaxFileSize(150_000);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        MultipartConfigurationContext.clear();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipartProperties.class)
public class MultipartConfiguration {

    private final MultipartProperties multipartProperties;

    public MultipartConfiguration(MultipartProperties multipartProperties) {
        this.multipartProperties = multipartProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = multipartProperties.createMultipartConfig();
        return new UpdatableMultipartConfigElement(multipartConfigElement.getLocation(), multipartConfigElement.getMaxFileSize(),
                multipartConfigElement.getMaxRequestSize(), multipartConfigElement.getFileSizeThreshold());
    }

    @Bean
    public UpdateMultipartConfigurationFilter updateMultipartConfigurationFilter() {
        return new UpdateMultipartConfigurationFilter();
    }
}
```

*Globally*

`UpdatableMultipartConfigElement` stores information which can be updated in runtime using rest api call.

```
public class UpdatableMultipartConfigElement extends MultipartConfigElement {

    private volatile long maxFileSize = -1;

    public UpdatableMultipartConfigElement(String location, long maxFileSize, long maxRequestSize, int fileSizeThreshold) {
        super(location, maxFileSize, maxRequestSize, fileSizeThreshold);
    }

    @Override
    public long getMaxFileSize() {
        return maxFileSize == -1 ? super.getMaxFileSize() : maxFileSize;
    }

    public void setMaxFileSize(long maxFileSize) {
        this.maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipartProperties.class)
public class MultipartConfiguration {

    private final MultipartProperties multipartProperties;

    public MultipartConfiguration(MultipartProperties multipartProperties) {
        this.multipartProperties = multipartProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = multipartProperties.createMultipartConfig();
        return new UpdatableMultipartConfigElement(multipartConfigElement.getLocation(), multipartConfigElement.getMaxFileSize(),
                multipartConfigElement.getMaxRequestSize(), multipartConfigElement.getFileSizeThreshold());
    }
}

@RestController
public class ConfigurationController {

    @Autowired
    private UpdatableMultipartConfigElement updatableMultipartConfigElement;

    @RequestMapping("/configuration")
    public void configuration(@RequestParam("maxFileSize") long maxFileSize) {
        updatableMultipartConfigElement.setMaxFileSize(maxFileSize);
    }

}
```

Comment: I promise to try this solution tomorrow

Comment: Second solution is working for me. Thank you very much!